# pg_query_params and pg function on DB

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm switching from `pg_exec` to `pg_query_param` and when I use a normal query everything it's ok but, I have a problem when I want to use a Postgres function on the database.

Here my actual code:

```
$sql = "select accsmap.prep_download_files('".$dataType."','{".
    $severity."}','{".
    $year."}','{".
    $region."}')";
$result = pg_exec($connect,$sql);
```

`$connect` it's just the DB info to connect to it.

and Here my new code:

```
$result = pg_query_params($connect,"select accsmap.prep_download_files( ".
"$1" ." ,{ ". "$2" ." },{ ". "$3" ." },{ ". "$4" ." });", 
array($dataType, $severity, $year, $region) );
```

I've tried a lot of ways to translate the `$sql` var into the query but always it returns me errors near `,` or `{` `}`

and here a sample of `$sql`

```
select accsmap.prep_download_files('for Accidents occuring in the following 
Authorities','{1,2,3}','{2014,2016}','{E08000001,E06000028,E06000036}')
```

The function expect `$severity`, `$year` and `$region` as array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way you are handling the parameters. For example:

```
pg_query_params($dbconn, 'SELECT * FROM shops WHERE name = $1', array("Joe's Widgets"));
```

If you see the query, there is a column called `name` (character data type) and it should be single quoted `name = 'name'`. But since it is inside the pg_query_params, you just use `name = $1` 'cause the function escapes the parameter and adds the quotes.

Therefore, since you use a postgreSQL array, it fails in constructing the query because your parameters arent well constructed. If your variable `$severity` is like this `$severity="1,2,3"` it will try to add a escaped parameter to the reference returning something like this: `{'1,2,3'}`.

On the other hand, If one of the parameters is an array like in your case (array of ints being passed to a stored procedure), it must be denoted as a set within the array, not php array notation.

I can't test the code, but I believe that the correct way to do it should be:

```
$severity='{1,2,3}';
$year='{2014,2016}';
$region='{E08000001,E06000028,E06000036}';
$result = pg_query_params($connect,"select accsmap.prep_download_files($1, $2, $3, $4)", 
array($dataType, $severity, $year, $region) );
```

Comment: the `var` are comma separated strings when they arrive from the hidden input element, like this `$severity='1,2,3';` at the end, a colleague found a way but I don't understand why I can't do it inside `pg_query_params` the solutions is: `$severity = fixtags(_cleanInputs($_POST['Severity']));` `$severity = '{'.$severity.'}';`

Comment: It looks like `fixtags` and `_cleanInputs` are **user** functions or methods. Most likely those functions format the data for the set. if you ´var_dump´ $severity before `$severity = '{'.$severity.'}';` you could see what the functions did, but just at a first glance it looks like it just makes `$severity='{1,2,3}'`

Comment: those functions are to sanitize the input, prevent SQL injection, if I var_dump the `var` I have just a string `$severity='1,2,3'`

Comment: Exactly ;)
First sanitize to get `$severity='1,2,3` so at the end with `$severity='{'.$severity.'}'` you get a var_dump like `$severity='{1,2,3}'`(see my answer).
You can't do it inside the `pg_query_params` because it is made to run a query with param references, and formats the params accordingly. In other words `pg_query_params` automatically adds the parameters to the query and rewrites the query; like I put in my answer, if you send `$severity='1,2,3'` in the param, the 'final' query will end up with `{'1,2,3'}` (quotes inside the keys), that is why it returns errors near `,` or `{ }`

Comment: I see, just a quick question, why in the placeholder `array` can I use `%` like `array($dataType, "%$severity", "%$year%", $region)` and not add the `{ }` ? I use this on another file for another query

Comment: `%` is not PHP but **SQL**. the parameter you are sending to the function would be (for example) `%2018%`. Since that is the interpretation of `"%$year%"`. The use depends on your query, generally we use `%` for matching any sequence of characters with `LIKE` [read more here](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-like/)